# Why does fractional computed line height cause css height transition to shake text?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I observed a weird effect today while working on something. I was using CSS height transition to change my website's header height and observed the whole website's text was shaking.

Eventually I was able to pinpoint the cause of it and it was fractional value of computed line height. Following is the effect:

```css
.hover {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
.hover:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  /*Computed line height is 19.5 -- fraction*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
Hover over me<br>
foo bar<br>
foo bar<br>
foo bar<br>

</div>
<p class="shake">
  I will shakeI will shakeI will shake <br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
</p>
```

Compare this to non-fractional computed line-height text:

```css
.hover {
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 1s ease;
}
.hover:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
p {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  /*Computed line height is 18 -- non-fraction*/
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">
Hover over me<br>
foo bar<br>
foo bar<br>
foo bar<br>

</div>
<p class="shake">
  I will shakeI will shakeI will shake <br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
  I will shake I will shakeI will shake<br>
</p>
```

So, why does it happen? What are possible ways to fix the shaking while keeping the fractional computed line-height?

Comment: How can you position something with float value on a screen that can only handle integers? Well you round it to an integer, which isn't the smoothest of transitions

Comment: @Randommm By floating it around the screen to floor the fraction to nearest integer that can animate that matrix3d enhanced by gpu acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I tell it is a combination of factors.

Some shaking occurs for me for any line height, for both 1.2 and 1.3.

As far as I can tell it occurs due to rounding of fractional positioning for each render during the transition.  A rounding of the fractional positioning will result from the height not being a non integer amount, because it is pushing down the text, and text line position being a non integer amount.

The height will be a non integer amount depending on the step size.  'ease' uses a default cubic-bezier function, which will result in a fractional height steps, also changing with time.  This added to non integer line heights (x 1 for line 1, x 2 for line 2, etc.) would result in rendering position in the view port which will jump around depenending on the rounding resulting in floor or celing integers, which will almost certainly be different for eash transition step and for each line of text.

To my eye the best result was for an integer line-height, say 1.2, a height change from 20px to 120px, with a transition-timing-function of steps(100), that is each line of text is positionally rendered at an integer number of pixels.

Comment: Very similar to Playstation 1 graphics and how the graphics would jitter for the same nuances in rounding.